# addeventlistener not working, event not waiting for on click

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener

I am working on a Javascript exercise for a web page and what I want is for a line of text to appear when I click on a button, problem is that the text just appears before I click on the button.  All my tags and ids are correct.

```
document.getElementById("earth_time").setAttribute("hidden", true);
ocument.getElementById("earth_time_check").addEventListener("onclick", earthTime());
function earthTime(){
document.getElementById("earth_time").innerHTML = Date();
document.getElementById("earth_time").hidden = false;}
```

Comment: What happens if you set the element using CSS instead of JS?  Like, set it to hidden in CSS, see if it hides, and then use JS to unhide it?  Could be illuminating to break the problem up a little like that.

Comment: I think you missed a letter "d" in the second line.

Comment: it is in the code, i just didn't paste it over in the question

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you try to set event listener to a result of the invocation of `earthTime` function, and it is effectively `undefined` because you return nothing from it.

The proper way to set event listener is:

```
document.getElementById("earth_time").setAttribute("hidden", true);
// earthTime is without calling brackets
document.getElementById("earth_time_check").addEventListener("onclick", earthTime);

function earthTime(){
  document.getElementById("earth_time").innerHTML = Date();
  document.getElementById("earth_time").hidden = false;
}
```

Comment: For other users that come across this question look at how earthTime is called, note that removing the ()'s on line 3 were required.
document.getElementById("earth_time_check").addEventListener("onclick", earthTime);

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, unless you may have made a typographical error on your second line of code.

```
document.getElementById("earth_time").setAttribute("hidden", true);
document.getElementById("earth_time_check").addEventListener("onclick", 
earthTime);

// define function earthTime
function earthTime(){
document.getElementById("earth_time").innerHTML = Date();
document.getElementById("earth_time").hidden = false;
}
```